# How to make a textarea accept javascript in my settings apge?

Tags: plugins, options

I'm building a simple plugin that will allow us to add code to our site header by defining it on our settings page. However I haven't been able to make it allow scripts.

This is my current code:

```
public function sanitize( $input )
{
    $new_input = array();

    if( isset( $input['code'] ) )
        $new_input['code'] = sanitize_text_field( $input['code'] );

    return $new_input;
}

public function code_callback()
{
    printf(
        '<textarea type="text" id="code" name="pl-analytics[code]">%s</textarea>',
        isset( $this->options['code'] ) ? esc_attr( $this->options['code']) : ''
    );
}
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Look at [sanitize_text_field()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_text_field). The codex says it strips all tags. If you're trying to use the `<script>` tag (or any HTML tag for that matter) inside your text-area, it will strip it.

Comment: I see, is there a way to allow javascript without creating a vulnerability? / What should I look for if I created my own sanitising function? If you post your answer I will accept it!

Comment: You will always have a vulnerability if you allow JS. You should reconsider what your need is and if it could be accomplished in another way.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way you can let JavaScript through without creating some kind of vulnerability. But the same is true of any filtering of inputs. As a developer you have to weigh up functionality against risk.

The wp_kses() function is probably what you're looking for. Have a read of [Otto's post](http://ottopress.com/2010/wp-quickie-kses/) to learn more about it.

It's also on the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_kses) too.

Below is a rough example. Untested as I've strangely never had to add script tags before.

```
public function sanitize( $input )
{
    $new_input = array();

    $allowed = array(
        'script'    => array(
            'src' => array()
        )
    );

    if( isset( $input['code'] ) )
        $new_input['code'] = wp_kses( $input['code'], $allowed );

    return $new_input;
}
```